# .NET MAUI: wrong namespace in new ContentPage

Tags: c#, maui

I have created a MAUI App with 'KnifeMaui' namespace.

Now when I add a new element->ContentPage it is generated with 'MauiApp1' namespace.

If I try to change it to 'KnifeMaui' I get an error for method InitializeComponent() (*the name does not exists in the current context*).

This is problem when in AppShell.xaml I try to set up an xmlns and it doesn't find KnifeMaui.Views.

I have looked in project properties but I haven't found any MauiApp1 reference.

Has anyone encountered this problem and fixed it?

Comment: if your new page is XAML, you will need to correct the namespace in both the XAML and the codebehind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently a bug in Visual Studio 17.4 preview 1. The MauiApp1 namespace should’ve been replaced with the project name.

As suggested by others there is an easy fix by just renaming that namespace to whatever it should be in your project. Hopefully the bug wil be fixed soon. You can follow the progress here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Problem-with-adding-new-page-to-project/10118293

Answer (score 1):

To fix this you need to make changes in XAML and C# side of things, since we have to link the two partials to each other.

In XAML side look for:

```
    x:Class="YourNameSpace.YourClassName"
```

On your Code-Behind C#:

```
namespace YourNameSpace;

public partial class YourClassName : Shell (Shell ContentPage whatever)
{
```

Comment: Thank you FreakyAli. The ContentPage is now fine but in AppShell.xaml xmlns KnifeMaui.Views is not recognized still.