# .NET MAUI InitialiseComponent doesn't exist

Tags: c#, .net, maui, .net-maui

I'm trying to get started with .NET maui on Mac, but even the starter hello world project doesn't run. I'm using the 17.4 preview and have all the maui tools installed, but it throws a bunch of errors when building with the mainpage.xaml.cs saying that the names InitalizeComponent() and CounterBtn don't exist. Initialize component seems to be fine in app.xaml.cs, so I'm not sure what the issue is

Comment: Double check the namespaces of pages and code behind (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73512696/net-maui-wrong-namespace-in-new-contentpage) )

Comment: Making a new application seems to have fixed the issue, not sure why it wasn't working originally